# Errors in dynamically inserting NSMenuItem in the main menu of cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I want to insert dynamically NSMenuItem in the main menu of cocoa application on top.I am using following code.

```
NSMenu *newMenu;
NSMenuItem *newItem;
newItem = [[NSMenuItem allocWithZone:[NSMenu menuZone]]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Language", @"Language") action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
newMenu = [[NSMenu allocWithZone:[NSMenu menuZone]]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Language", @"Language")];
[newItem setSubmenu:newMenu];
[[NSApp mainMenu] insertItem:newItem atIndex:5];//error comes here
newItem = [[NSMenuItem allocWithZone:[NSMenu menuZone]] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"English (EN)", @"nil") action:NULL keyEquivalent:@"E"];
[newItem setAction:@selector(someMethod:)];
[newMenu addItem:newItem];
```

but at this line `[[NSApp mainMenu] insertItem:newItem atIndex:5];` i am getting following error.

```
Invalid parameter not satisfying: (index >= 0) && (index <= [_itemArray count])
```

Comment: so how many menu items already exist in the menu you are trying to insert to? thats your problem. you likely meant index `4`;

Comment: i tried by 0 to 10...still same problem...i also tried [[NSApp mainMenu] addItem:newItem]; in this case i am not getting any error but menu item is not getting added